# Postgresql equivalent of mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

I'm considering moving a service from mysql to postgresql(latest version). Is there any straightforward equivalent of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` mysql clause? I've `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` but that is quite convoluted as it requires you to rewrite the entire `INSERT` statement into an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: `on conflict do update set ...` is the only option you have.

Comment: it looks like that's the case... postgre seems to like verbosity more than any other db...

Answer (score 0):

To use the upsert feature in PostgreSQL, you use the INSERT ON CONFLICT statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_list) 
VALUES(value_list)
ON CONFLICT target action;
```

PostgreSQL added the ON CONFLICT target action clause to the INSERT statement to support the upsert feature.

In this statement, the **target** can be one of the following:

(column_name) – a column name.
ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name – where the constraint name could be the name of the UNIQUE constraint.
WHERE predicate – a WHERE clause with a predicate.

The **action** can be one of the following:

DO NOTHING – means do nothing if the row already exists in the table.
DO UPDATE SET column_1 = value_1, .. WHERE condition – update some fields in the table.

```
INSERT INTO customers (name, email)
VALUES('user1','abc@xyz.com') 
ON CONFLICT (name) 
DO 
   UPDATE SET email = EXCLUDED.email || ';' || customers.email;
```

For references you can refer:- [postgresql-upsert](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/)